# UIAlertController with square (not rounded) corners

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

Is it possible to make the `UIAlertController` have square corners instead of the default rounded corners?

(I know it's possible with a third party library, but I want to know how to do it with apples `UIAlertController`.)

Comment: @soulshined gave you an excellent answer. The quote he provided was on the very first screen of the UIAlertController Class Reference in Xcode. Did you read the docs at all before posting your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, no, at this time Apple does not provide an *approved* API method to style your `UIAlertController` outside of the given circumstances. Changing this could result in a rejection as it doesn't obey their guidelines:

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

[See here for reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/)

Comment: Good answer. Clear, to the point, and well supported by a quote from the docs. (Voted)

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you can change cornerRadius with simple traverse:

```
extension UIView {
    func traverseRadius(_ radius: Float) {
        layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(radius)

        for subview: UIView in subviews {
            subview.traverseRadius(radius)
        }
    }
}
```

You can then present alert controller with:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
alertController.view.traverseRadius(0)
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Same thing in Objective C:

```
// UIView+TraverseRadius.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (TraverseRadius)
- (void)traverseRadius:(CGFloat)radius;
@end


// UIView+TraverseRadius.m
#import "UIView+TraverseRadius.h"

@implementation UIView (TraverseRadius)

- (void)traverseRadius:(CGFloat)radius {
    [self.layer setValue:@(radius) forKey:@"cornerRadius"];

    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        [subview traverseRadius:radius];
    }
}
@end
```

Include the header and use the following in the implementation:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[alertController.view traverseRadius:0];    
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You will get perfectly square UIAlertController:

### [image: Square Alert View Controller]

This code will not crash in future iOS versions, as cornerRadius is standard property of every UIView layer and you are not using any private methods or properties for achieving this.

Answer (score 4):

When added this line, made the alert corners square. myAlert.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

Comment: This doesn't square the corners, it makes the background visible